# I'm trying to take multiple NSTextFields and copy ALL contents to clipboard so the user can paste the form anywhere

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

Example:

Customer Name:(NSTextField)
Customer Number: (NSTextField)

(Button) "Copy Notes)

So when you hit the button to copy and the person goes to a text file and then pastes, I want it to look like this.

Customer Name: Brenda L.
Customer Number: 555-555-5555

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGUAO.jpg)

**Code Added:**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var customername: NSTextField!





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

NSPasteboard.general().string; customername

               }

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
    pasteboard().string = customername.text
```

**Edit:**

It worked! But,

One last question - How do I get the next field on the next line so they are not all on the same line when it is pasted.

```
let stringvalue = "Customer Name: \(customername.stringValue) Customer Number: \(custnum.stringValue)"
```

I want the paste output to look like this

Customer Name: Brenda
Customer Number: 555-555-5555

Comment: `UITextField` (iOS) or OS X and Cocoa (`NSTextField`)?

Comment: I added an image. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

In order to save data to clipboard you would use this:

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "this is your text"
```

So you could have the follow code in the button action:

```
let name = customername.text
let number = customernumber.text

UIPasteboard.general.string = "Customer Name: \(name) \(number)"
```

**EDIT:**

For mac OS:

```
let stringvalue = customername.stringValue

let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general()

pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboardTypeString], owner: nil)

pasteboard.setString(stringvalue, forType: NSPasteboardTypeString)
```

**EDIT 2**:

In order to print a string on two lines you use the \n character in the middle so your code would look like this:

```
let stringvalue = "Customer Name: \(customername.stringValue) \n Customer Number: \(custnum.stringValue)"
```

Comment: I added an image. Take a look

Comment: the answer does what you asked. It takes 2 fields and copies them both to clipboard. What else do you want it to do?

Comment: you have to click on the button on the storyboard, then hold "alt" and then drag it to your code. That will create an action. You put the code in there. That will allow that code to run whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: Oh, I'm doing this for COCOA Application that is why it's not working. The button kept giving me errors.

Comment: This is what I have so far, still getting an error.

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    IBOutlet weak var customername: NSTextField!
    

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
    NSPasteboard.general().string; customername
        
                   }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }

    IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
        pasteboard().string = customername.text

Comment: what error are you getting? Also please post your code in your original question and format it to code.

Comment: I sent you an email

Comment: I can send you an email - Is that ok?

Comment: Please post your code and error in your original question.

Comment: ok, I added an edit. If you could correct it for me. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your not suppose to edit my answer with your code. Your suppose to edit your original question and put your code in there.

Comment: My apologies I'm very new to this. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I updated my answer. Check the Mac os section of my answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have one more question added to it.

Comment: @BrennanPrill did this solve your problem or did you need anything else? Please accept this answer so others can view it.